Time Reversal Operator On Circular Polarised Light
What happens when we apply the time-reversal operator to circularly polarized light? Does right-handed circular light transform into left-handed circular light? I think the propagation direction and rotation will change, but I'm confused. Could you please answer?

Can you write the equations for the two transverse components of the E field for a plane wave of left and right circularly polarized light? Write those equations for light going the other way. Substitute $-t$ for $t$ in the first set. Which equations did it transform into?

When I replace t with -t in the electric field equations, the propagation direction of the light changes, but its handedness does not.

Likewise when you reverse the motion of a screw, the direction of propagation changes, but the handedness does not.

When we apply the time-reversal operator, the propagation direction changes, but the handedness of the light remains the same.
